# Sequelize 'reverse' hasOne?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm building an application where I have 3 main models:

Clinic, Doctor, Appointment

Both the Doctors and the Appointments belong to the Clinic through a `clinic_id` column, so Clinics can have multiple of each.
A Doctor can only belong to one Clinic.
Every appointment has one doctor assigned to it (`doctor_id`)

Sometimes I have to query the Appointment by id, and then I want to `include` Clinic and Doctor as well on the query, which should be simple as the Appoitment has `clinic_id` and `doctor_id`.

How can I include those ? I tried adding `Appointment.hasOne(Doctor, {foreignKey: doctor_id})` but it then tries to find the `doctor_id` column on the Doctor, not on the Appointment.
I would try Doctor.belongsTo(Appointment) but the Doctor actually belongs to the Clinic.

Can I tell `hasOne` to look for the `doctor_id` column on the `Appointment` model ?

Comment: "I would try Doctor.belongsTo(Appointment) but the Doctor actually belongs to the Clinic" – models can belong to multiple models.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an association using `belongsTo`:

```
Appointment.belongsTo(Doctor, { foreignKey: 'doctor_id' })
Appointment.belongsTo(Clinic, { foreignKey: 'clinic_id' })
```

According to your description of models you have `Clinic`-`Doctor` as 1:N, `Clinic`-`Appointment` as 1:N and `Appointment`-`Doctor` as N:1.

All other associations should look like this:

```
Doctor.belongsTo(Clinic, { foreignKey: 'clinic_id' })
Doctor.hasMany(Appointment, { foreignKey: 'doctor_id' })
Clinic.hasMany(Appointment, { foreignKey: 'clinic_id' })
Clinic.hasMany(Doctor, { foreignKey: 'clinic_id' })
```